# How do I get the value of a checkbox on click

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have an html table with a checkbox created dynamically on each row. The checked status of the checkbox is set based on a value in the database. When the checkbox is checked in the html table, I need to catch the change and set the value so that if the box is checked, value=1 else value=0. Value is passed to the update query. I'm not sure how to accomplish this with my current code.

HTML:

```
<?php 
    $sqlGetEmployees = "select e.employeeID, e.lastName, e.firstName, l.number, p.name, e.gradeCertLevel, e.serviceYears, e.step, e.certified from employee e join location l on l.locationID = e.locationID join position p on p.positionID = e.positionID";
    $stmtGetEmployees = mysqli_prepare($db,$sqlGetEmployees);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtGetEmployees);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmtGetEmployees, $id, $lastName, $firstName, $number, $name, $gradeCertLevel, $serviceYears, $salaryStep, $certified);

    $count = 1; 

   while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmtGetEmployees))
   {
        $checkedCertified = ($certified == '1') ? 'checked="checked"':'';
?>
    <tr>
        <!-- other table data -->
        <td> 
            <div id='certified_<?php echo $id; ?>'>
                <input contentEditable='true' class='edit' type='checkbox' id='certified' <?php echo $checkedCertified; ?> />
            </div> 
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
        $count ++;
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmtGetEmployees);
?>
```

Script:

```
    // Add Class
    $('.edit').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('editMode');

    });

    // Save data
    $(".edit").focusout(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("editMode");

        var id = this.id;
        var split_id = id.split("_");
        var field_name = split_id[0];
        var edit_id = split_id[1];

        var value = $(this).text();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'update.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { field:field_name, value:value, id:edit_id },
            success:function(response){
                console.log('Save successfully');               
            }
        });

    });
```

update PHP

```
$field = $_POST['field'];
$value = $_POST['value'];
$editid = $_POST['id'];
$checkedStatus = $_POST['checked'];

if($field == "certified")
{
    $sqlUpdateCertified = "UPDATE employee SET ".$field."=? WHERE employeeID= ?";
    $stmtUpdateCertified = mysqli_prepare($db,$sqlUpdateCertified);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtUpdateCertified, "ss",$checkedStatus,$editid);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtUpdateCertified);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmtUpdateCertified);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with *need to catch the change and set the value*?

Comment: I assume that when the box is checked initial and then it's clicked, the value changes. When that event happens, I need the value set to a 1 if checked and 0 if unchecked.

Comment: @choooper2006 Better to use `true` and `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically created elements events are handled like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(e) {
   //e.preventDefault();
   var checkedStatus = 0;
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $(this).addClass('editMode');
       checkedStatus = 1;
   } else {
       checkedStatus = 0;
       $(this).removeClass("editMode");
   }  

    var id = this.id;
    var split_id = id.split("_");
    var field_name = split_id[0];
    var edit_id = split_id[1];

    var value = $(this).text();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'update.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { field:field_name, value:value, id:edit_id, checked: checkedStatus },
        success:function(response){
            console.log('Save successfully');               
        }
    });
});
```

To put everything in a single event handler you can either put everything in .click or .focusout depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: When I made those changes, the box will not check or uncheck on the webpage because of the `e.preventDefault();`. What is the purpose of this line?

Comment: preventDefault prevents the default action from triggering, for example if you click on the <a element the link wont work. You can remove it, I copied my snippet and I have it there by default so I forgot about it

Comment: @choooper2006 I've edited my answer, I also forgot to add else in the event handler, everything should be fine now

Comment: The value isn't getting updated in the database. If I echo the variable that I set with the 'checkedStatus', at the end of the PHP script to be sent back in the response, it's empty. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @choooper2006 Are you using $_POST['checked'] to access the variable value in PHP?

Comment: I was not and I have edited the PHP script and have the value now. But the PHP is not updating the value in the database. Do you see anything with the script? It has been updated in the question.

Comment: I found the issue with the PHP script. It's not getting `$_POST['id']` when the checkbox is changed but it is getting the field name.

Comment: That probably because your ajax request is dispatched from .focusout event, while checked status is changed in the .click event. You should try to put all the logic in one event handler if possible.

Comment: That makes sense. Can you provide an example of what that would look like? I'm new to jquery and trying to figuring this out as I go.

Comment: I edited my answer to show one of the options, I hope it works, it is kinda hard to do this kind of detailed coding from a distance, without fully unterstanding exactly what you are trying to achive.

Comment: Thank you for providing the example. Turns put the issue was in the html. I changed it to `<td> <div><input contentEditable='true' class='edit' type='checkbox' id='certified_<?php echo $id; ?>' <?php echo $checkedCertified; ?> /></div> </td>`. Thank you very much for your help!